# Remove duplicate words from a column cell using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, character

Remove duplicate words from a column cell, for example:

Data column this is a single field: '`BLACKHEATH 0AA  BLACKHEATH COLCHESTER CO2 0AA` '

But I want like this, "BLACKHEATH" should only be once, if any other entry is found then it should be removed

```
BLACKHEATH COLCHESTER CO2 0AA
```

I can do this through code, but I've no idea how to remove duplicate words through SQL in SQL Server. I've been instructed to do this through SQL.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: i want function in Sql server,

Comment: SQL Server has replace() function, did you look at that?

Comment: yes but its replace every word who same as , i want more then one word function

Comment: Where do you want to place the first occurrence of the repeated word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @text varchar(max) = 'BLACKHEATH 0AA BLACKHEATH COLCHESTER CO2 0AA'
declare @i int = 1;
declare @nextCharacter varchar(max)
declare @word varchar(max)=''

declare @lastChar varchar(1) = substring(@text,len(@text),1)
--select @lastChar

declare @lastIndex varchar(max) = charindex(@lastChar,@text,len(@text))
select @lastIndex
--select len(@text)

create table #tmp (id int,word varchar(max))

while (@i <= len(@text))
begin

    select @nextCharacter= substring(@text, @i, 1)
    --select @nextCharacter,@i, @lastChar, len(@text)

    if (@nextCharacter !=' ')
        begin       
            select @word = @word + @nextCharacter
        end

     else
        begin
            insert into #tmp
            values(@i,@word)
            set @word=''
        end
         if (@i = len(@text) and @nextCharacter= @lastChar)
        begin
        insert into #tmp
            values(@i,@word)                    
        end

    set @i = @i +1

end;

select id,word from #tmp order by id;

WITH tblTemp as
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() Over(PARTITION BY word ORDER BY id)
   As RowNumber,* FROM #tmp
) --select * from tblTemp
select * into #tmp2 FROM tblTemp where RowNumber =1 

declare @newString varchar(max)=''
select @newString = @newString +word+' ' from #tmp2 order by id 

select rtrim(@newString)

drop table #tmp2
drop table #tmp
```

Answer (score 5):

If the order doesn't matter, you could do it quite quite easily:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(100) = 'BLACKHEATH 0AA  BLACKHEATH COLCHESTER CO2 0AA';

SELECT @string AS Source
    , LTRIM((
            SELECT DISTINCT ' ' + column1 AS [text()]
            FROM dbo.SplitString(@string, ' ')
            FOR XML PATH('')
            )) AS UniqueWords;
```

What's the idea here?

1. `dbo.SplitString` function splits your string into rows based on delimiter
   (`space` in your case). See [this article](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) to find SplitString function that suits your needs best.
2. `DISTINCT` keyword removed dupes
3. Using `FOR XML PATH('')` we concatenate them back together.

**Result:**

```
╔═══════════════════════════════════════════════╦═══════════════════════════════╗
║                    Source                     ║          UniqueWords          ║
╠═══════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════╣
║ BLACKHEATH 0AA  BLACKHEATH COLCHESTER CO2 0AA ║ 0AA BLACKHEATH CO2 COLCHESTER ║
╚═══════════════════════════════════════════════╩═══════════════════════════════╝
```

If you need to keep order, you'd have to create a function that stores your terms in original order (probably using [ROW_NUMBER()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)) and has order for each seperate term (to remove dupes) and then you could calculate where each words need to be. I didn't bother creating it, but it should output such result for your string:

```
╔═══════════╦═══════════╦════════════╗
║ WordOrder ║ TermOrder ║    Term    ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════╬════════════╣
║         1 ║         1 ║ BLACKHEATH ║
║         2 ║         1 ║ 0AA        ║
║         3 ║         2 ║ BLACKHEATH ║
║         4 ║         1 ║ COLCHESTER ║
║         5 ║         1 ║ CO2        ║
║         6 ║         2 ║ 0AA        ║
╚═══════════╩═══════════╩════════════╝
```

Which could be reused in such a query(`@Splitted` is table above):

```
SELECT @string AS Source
    , LTRIM((
            SELECT ' ' + Term AS [text()]
            FROM @Splitted
            WHERE TermOrder = 1
            ORDER BY WordOrder
            FOR XML PATH('')
            )) AS UniqueWords;
```

It ouputs this string:

```
╔═══════════════════════════════════════════════╦═══════════════════════════════╗
║                    Source                     ║          UniqueWords          ║
╠═══════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════╣
║ BLACKHEATH 0AA  BLACKHEATH COLCHESTER CO2 0AA ║ BLACKHEATH 0AA COLCHESTER CO2 ║
╚═══════════════════════════════════════════════╩═══════════════════════════════╝
```

P.S. Why you were instructed to do this in SQL? SQL Server doesn't deal well with text data, thus I'd recommend doing this in code as it might affect your performance.

Comment: What is `GetTableFromList` ? where is it defined ? i can't see any reference for it. Can you please tell more about it ? thx

Comment: Should've been `dbo.StringSplit()`. It's a common utility function to split a delimited string into table of values.

Comment: 'StringSplit()' also not working, you may need to add the underscore `_` in between: `STRING_SPLIT`

Answer (score -2):

```
declare @text varchar(max) = 'BLACKHEATH 0AA BLACKHEATH COLCHESTER CO2 0AA'
declare @i int = 1;
declare @nextCharacter varchar(max)
declare @word varchar(max)=''

declare @lastChar varchar(1) = substring(@text,len(@text),1)
--select @lastChar

declare @lastIndex varchar(max) = charindex(@lastChar,@text,len(@text))
select @lastIndex
--select len(@text)

create table #tmp (id int,word varchar(max))

while (@i <= len(@text))
begin

    select @nextCharacter= substring(@text, @i, 1)
    --select @nextCharacter,@i, @lastChar, len(@text)

    if (@nextCharacter !=' ')
        begin       
            select @word = @word + @nextCharacter
        end

     else
        begin
            insert into #tmp
            values(@i,@word)
            set @word=''
        end
         if (@i = len(@text) and @nextCharacter= @lastChar)
        begin
        insert into #tmp
            values(@i,@word)                    
        end

    set @i = @i +1

end;

--select id,word from #tmp order by id;

WITH tblTemp as
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() Over(PARTITION BY word ORDER BY id)
   As RowNumber,* FROM #tmp
) --select * from tblTemp
select * into #tmp2 FROM tblTemp where RowNumber =1 

declare @newString varchar(max)=''
select @newString = @newString +word+' ' from #tmp2 order by id 

select rtrim(@newString) as FromAddress

drop table #tmp2
drop table #tmp
```

Please remove id in select clause.